# Update value to specific primary key in sqlite , android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have to below table structure of my sqlite database in android

[image: Table Strucre]

I want to update value to "answer" column according to the ques id.

How do I do it?

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_Answer, answer);
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_Question, null, values);

    db.close(); // Closing database connection
```

Comment: Use the update function by passing ques id in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to insert value to "answer" column according to the ques id.

This operation called "update" instead of "insert".

**insert**: means to add new record in table,

**update**: means change value of any exist row columns

so required operation is update.use update method as:

```
String where = "Ques_id=?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(Ques_id)};

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_Answer, answer);
db.update(TABLE_Question, values, where, whereArgs);
```

Answer (score 0):

`insert()` inserts a new row. To update a column on an existing row, use `update()` with a selection like `"Ques_id=" + id`.